# Query regarding cooling off period for Work permit up to 120 days max

Tags: schengen-visas, switzerland, repeat-visits, zurich, work-permit

I have a query regarding cooling off period for visa type "Work permit up to 120 days". 
My job requires me to travel to Zurich repeatedly (every year), hence it is important for me to know the below details.

1. What is the cooling period in Zurich canton to re-apply for the same visa type ("Work permit up to 120 days")?
2. Does the 12 months cooling period start after I enter Switzerland or after I leave from Switzerland?

E.g. Last time I was in Switzerland on a 120 days work permit starting on 20th Dec 2017 and left from Switzerland on 18th April 2018. With this information when can I reapply for the same Visa type "Work permit up to 120 days"?

Comment: Assuming your profile is accurate and you are from Pune (India), you're not an EU/EFTA citizen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Internationallawoffice](https://www.internationallawoffice.com/Newsletters/Immigration/Switzerland/Suter-Howald-Attorneys-at-Law/Cooling-off-periods-for-non-EUEFTA-nationals-in-Switzerland):

> **Article 56 of the Decree on Admittance, Residence and Employment states that a short-term work permit can be renewed only after a 12-month interruption or cooling-off period.** This means that a person who has left and been de-registered from Switzerland must wait 12 months outside Switzerland before being able to obtain a new work permit.
>
> **Exceptions are possible in reasonable individual cases, especially in case of recurring activities.**

This means you will have to wait 12 months from the time of exit in order to apply for a new permit.

If you have to travel more often than a year, you can state this in your application stating you have regular repeating work.